# integration by parts $ \int xe^{-2x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Can you guys help me integrate $ \int xe^{-2x} dx$ using integration by parts?

---

So far I got an answer using this
$$u = x \qquad dv = e^{-2x}dx \\ du = dx \qquad v = \frac{-e^{-2x}}{2} $$
so that would mean that
$$ - \frac{-xe^{-2x}}{2} - \int  \frac{-e^{-2x}}{2}dx$$
and the final answer would have been
$$ \frac{-xe^{-2x}}{2} - e^{-2x} + c$$
is this correct or should i have interchanged my $u$ and $dv$?

Comment: Can you do the integral which results from the IBP formula?  If you can then the working was successful, if not then one of the things you could try is to interchange $u$ and $v$.

Comment: see this link, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts just choose now the right functions for $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ Hint for this: you see in the integral that there appears $u'(x)$, so it would be nice if this would be 1

Comment: yes i could and i got an answer but i tried interchanging the two and i got a different answer, the problem would then be to decide which one is correct

Comment: Please check your work for $\int -\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}$

Comment: should it be [-e^(-2x)]/4??? sorry i'm very confused right now

Comment: it should be $-e^{-2x}/4$  and not $-e^{-2X}$

Comment: oh i see!!!! now the answers are the same even if i intercahnge my u and v!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYSS

Answer (score 3):

You begin parts from the exponential, that is:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int x e^{-2x}\,dx &=-\frac{1}{2} xe^{-2x}+\frac{1}{2}\int (x)' e^{-2x}\,dx \\ 
 &=-\frac{1}{2}xe^{-2x}+\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-2x}\,dx \\ 
 &= -\frac{1}{2}xe^{-2x}-\frac{1}{4}e^{-2x}+c, \;\;  c \in \mathbb{R}\\ 
\end{aligned}$$

done.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(-\frac{xe^{-2x}}{2} - e^{-2x} + c\right)'=-\frac{e^{-2x}}2+xe^{-2x}+2e^{-2x}.$$

You visibly messed up with a factor...